# How to prove the triangle inequality for this metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \{0,1\}$ which can be viewed as the set of all sequences of binary digits. For $f,g \in X$, with $f \neq g$, define $m(f, g) = \min\{k : f(k) \neq g(k)\}$ and define $d : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$d(f, g) = \begin{cases}2^{-m(f,g)} & \text{if } f \neq g \\ 0 & \text{if }f = g.\end{cases}$$

The first three axioms have been given I imagine the first starting point is to prove that

$$m(a,c) \ge  \min\{m(a,b), m(b,c)\}.$$

Followed by:

> For $f \in X$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $B(f, 2^{-n})$ consists of all $g \in X$ for which
>   $$f(1) = g(1), f(2) = g(2), \ldots, \text{ and }f(n) = g(n).$$

This I think you must use the previous fact that $d(f,g) = 2^{-m(f,g)}$.

Followed by:

> Show that for all $f \in X$, $r > 0$, either $B'(f,r) = B(f,r)$ or $B'(f,r) = B(f,2r)$.

This I believe must be a continuity using open sets problem.

Comment: Please do mathJax, so difficult to read your question.. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry I don't really know how to do it

Comment: I was going to edit your question to format it properly, but then I noticed that you've been here for almost a year now (happy anniversary, in $5$ days time!) and have asked four prior questions that others have all formatted for you. So, unfortunately, this time I'm just going to down-vote. If you do format your question, give me a ping in the comments (@TheoBendit) and I'll remove the down-vote, attempt to answer the question, and give you an up-vote to boot. If you have any questions about using MathJax, ask [Meta](https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/). Good luck!

Comment: Alexander, it really does not take much effort, but you have not put it in for 360 days! If you don't know how to do it, then learn it, or keep the MathJax documentation page open while you're typing! I did this for six months , and eventually rote learned all the simple commands. Take the time to do it, because your question ticks *all the boxes* and deserves attention and upvotes, except for its legibility. (Yes, you are starting  to change it, that is good!)

Comment: @TheoBendit somewhat better now, I have been meaning to learn LaTeX but have never gotten around to it.

Comment: @AlexanderQuinn Removing the down-vote for effort, but I'd like to see a little bit more done before I come in and clean it up for you. You can press "edit" on your previous questions to see how others have formatted them, and you can even try changing things to test how it affects the layout. Here are some simple commands too: `\neq` = "$\neq$", `\in` = "$\in$", `\ge` = "$\ge$". Try putting `$` signs around most of the maths, and it will already look much better. If you try another edit, I'll finish it up for you if you wish.

Comment: Oh, and if you want your set brackets to appear (instead of disappear and be used by MathJax for grouping purposes), try writing `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: Looking better. You can use `\min` for $\min$, as opposed to `min` for $min$. Many common functions/operators like this can be formatted with a simple \ (e.g. `\sin`). You can also use `\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}` to get $\prod_{n=1}^\infty$. Finally, `\mathbb{R}` will produce $\Bbb{R}$ and similarly for $\Bbb{N}$. If you want though, I can step in and do the rest.

Comment: That would be great if you could please do that

Comment: Put \not before any keyboard character to get a forward slash through it, e.g.  \not \in, \not <, \not \equiv, \not me : $\not \in, \not <, \not \equiv, \not me$. I usually type a paragraph without dollar signs and then add them all. This makes me re-read it too, so I catch errors and typos.

Comment: $What is B'???$

Comment: The closed ball

Comment: To confirm, the first part of the question is prove that $d$ is a metric?

Comment: Yes I think that d satisfies the metric space axioms 1, 2 and 3 but to prove the triangle inequality is the hard part

Comment: Be careful in metric spaces to distinguish between the set  $\overline {B(f,r)}$ (formatted \overline {B(f,r)} ), which is the  the closure of $\{g:d(f,g)<r\},$ and the set $\{g: d(f,g)\le r\},$ as these may be different things.

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be a format over line on just the B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f \ne g \ne h \ne f.$ Let $a=m(f,g),\,b=m(g,h), \,c=m(f,h).$

Suppose $d(f,g)+d(g,h)<d(f,h).$

Then $ 2^{-a}+2^{-b}<2^{-c},$ which implies $(\,c<a \land c<b\,). $  But then  $$ f(c)=g(c)\quad (\text { as  }c<a=m(f,g)\,)$$ $$ \text {and } \quad g(c)=h(c)\quad  (\text { as } c<b=m(g,h)\,)$$ so $f(c)=h(c),$ contrary to the def'n of $c=m(f,h).$ Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! So then perhaps the second part can be done by contradiction also?\

Comment: This is a very nice answer.

Comment: For the last  part:... (I).... If $n\in \Bbb N$ and $r=2^{-n},$ consider any $g \not \in B(f,r).$ Let $m\le n$ such that  $g(m)\ne f(m) .$ Now for any $h\in B(f,r)$ we have $h(m)=f(m)\ne g(n)$. So $d(g,h)\ge 2^{-m}$ for all $h\in B(f,r)$  so $g \not \in \overline {B(f,r)}$..... (II).... For other $r,$ consider this example: If $r=1/6$ then $ h\in B(f,r)\iff d(f,h)<1/6\iff d(f,h)\le 1/8 \iff d(f,h)<1/4.$  So $B(f,1/6)=B(f,1/4) $....And by (I), $B(f,1/4)$ is closed..... NOTE:  In this example, $B(f,2r)=B(f,1/3),$ which is NOT the closure of $B(f,1/6).$

Answer (score 3):

If $a(i)$ agrees with $b(i)$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, m(a, b) - 1$. Similarly, $b(i)$ agrees with $c(i)$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, m(b, c) - 1$. So, we have $a(i) = b(i) = c(i)$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, k$, where $k = \min \{m(a, b), m(b, c)\} - 1$, as $k$ is a number smaller than both $m(a, b) - 1$ and $m(b, c) - 1$. Therefore, $m(a, c)$, the first $i$ such that $a(i) \neq c(i)$, must be at least $k + 1$. That is,
$$m(a, c) \ge \min\{m(a, b), m(b, c)\}.$$

Thus, excluding the easy cases where $a, b, c$ are not pairwise distinct,
\begin{align*}
d(a, b) + d(b, c) &= 2^{-m(a, b)} + 2^{-m(b, c)} \\
&= 2^{-\max\{m(a, b), m(b, c)\}} + 2^{-\min\{m(a, b), (b, c)\}} \\
&\ge 2^{-\min\{m(a, b), (b, c)\}} \\
&\ge 2^{-m(a, c)} = d(a, c).
\end{align*}

---

If $g \in B(f, 2^{-n})$, then either $f = g$ (in which case, the result is trivially true), or
$$2^{-n} > d(f, g) = 2^{-m(a, b)} \implies m(a, b) > n.$$
So, the first point at which $f$ and $g$ disagree occurs past $n$, i.e. $f(i) = g(i)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

---

Note that the distance function $d(f, g)$ only takes countably many values:
$$0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \ldots, \frac{1}{2^n}, \ldots$$
When $r$ is between these values, the ball $B(f; r)$ will not grow or shrink when you vary $r$ by a small amount. For example, for any $f \in X$,
$$B\left(f, \frac{1}{3}\right) = B\left(f, \frac{1}{2}\right) = B'\left(f, \frac{1}{4}\right),$$
simply because a point that at most $\frac{1}{3}$ distance away from $f$, basically only rules out their distances being $\frac{1}{2}$.

This might give you an idea about how to go about attacking this third problem. I'll let you think about it. Let me know via comment if you need further help.

Comment: So the main thing in the last question is that we need to prove for any f ∈ X and radius r, the closure of the open ball of radius r around x is the closed ball of radius r.

Comment: @AlexanderQuinn Well actually, every open ball is closed, and is equal to a closed ball! But. not necessarily the closed ball of the same radius as the open ball. The closure of $B(f, 1/2)$ is $B(f, 1/2) = B'(f, 1/4)$, not $B(f, 1/2)$ (which is equal to $X$).

Comment: So it must be the B(f,r) = B'(f,r) is the only reasonable one out of the two as if you take the limit you eventually approach 0 for r

Comment: (In my previous comment, the third (and last) instance of $B(f, 1/2)$ should be $B'(f, 1/2)$)

Comment: @AlexanderQuinn I'm not certain what you mean here. You will have $B(f, r) = B'(f, r)$ when $r$ is not $0$ or a negative power of $2$, as in this case, the difference between the sets (which is the sphere $S(f, r)$) is empty! If $r$ is not one of these numbers, then there are no points in the space of distance exactly $r$ from each other.

Comment: Ah I see now so a argument must be constructed to show that r is not zero or a negative power of two

Comment: @AlexanderQuinn Well, according to the there are two cases: $B'(f, r) = B(f, r)$ or $B'(f, r) = B(f, 2r)$. So, try dealing with $r$ being $0$, $r$ being a negative power of $2$, and all other values of $r$ as separate cases. In the third case, as we've just seen, $B'(f, r) = B(f, r)$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $a\in X$ and radius $r$, the closure of the open ball of radius $r$ around $a$ is the closed ball of radius $r$.

For any two distinct points $a,b$ in the space and any positive $\epsilon$, there is a point $c$ within $\epsilon$ of $b$, and closer to $a$ than $b$ is. 
That is, for every $a\neq b$ and $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is $c$ with $d(c,b)<\epsilon$ and $d(a,c)<d(a,b)$.

Proof. If the closed ball property holds, then fix any $a,b$ with $r=d(a,b)$. Since the closure of $B$ includes $b$, the second property follows. Conversely, if the second property holds, then if $r=d(a,b)$, then the property ensures that $b$ is in the closure of $B$, and so the closure of the open ball includes the closed ball